# Bizarre error on address of class with templated member

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, memory-address

I encountered a weird error when modifying my class structures, which I couldn't reproduce with simpler classes.

## Situation:

I have decided to have a class `Input` have a reference (a plain old pointer) to the object to be manipulated by the user's key input, `Camera`. Previously I linked them via `Input`'s constructor: `Input in(&cam);` but after including a templated member in Camera: `Buffer<Layout> buffer` my whole main function went berserk.

Previously this was fine:

```
Camera cam();
Input in(&cam);
cam.setProj(glm::mat4(1.0f));    // Example of function call
```

The headers are of course in separate files, and the implementations in .cpp-files.

`Input` has a member `Camera *cam` and the constructor for `Input` is:

```
Input::Input(Camera *camera){
    this->cam = camera;
}
```

## Problem:

It no longer is fine. The error message is:

> Input::Input(Input &&): cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'Camera(__cdecl *)(void)' to 'Camera *'

Additionally, every attempt to call `Camera`'s functions gives two additional errors: `expression must have class type` and `left of '.func' must have class/struct/union`.

## Attempt to create a minimal example:

Tl;dr: didn't quite get there. Or at least the issue isn't directly in taking the address of a class with a template member. The following code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class Member{
public:
    Member(T variable):var(variable){};
    T var;
};

class Owner{
public:
    Owner(int m):member(m){};
    Member<int> member;
};

class Referencer{
public:
    Referencer(Owner *o){this->op = o;};
    Owner *op;
};

int main(){
    Owner o(1);
    Referencer r(&o);
    printf("%d\n", r.op->member);    // Output is 1.

    return 0;
}
```

As the above example works, I'm not sure whether it actually affects the situation to have a template member. I'm really lost with this one. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `Camera cam();`? Then it is a declaration of a function with no parameters and return type `Camera`. It could explain the error.

Comment: @AlexD Actually yes! But how would one initialize the object if not by using the default constructor like that?

Comment: `Cam cam;` should do what you want.

Comment: @AlexD Once again, a stupidly simple mishap :D Oh my.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Camera cam();
```

It is a simple function declaration. You declare a function returning `Camera` and accepting zero arguments. And your MSVC compiler complains about it!

> Input::Input(Input &&): cannot convert argument 1 from **'Camera(__cdecl *)(void)'** to 'Camera *'

Just use:

```
Camera cam;
```

and let the default constructor to be called.